# "CANNOT GET /" error on Express application

Tags: html, json, express

I just started an application with express. In my project folder I have my index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');

//App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('listening to requests on port 4000');
});

//Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

And inside that folder I have a 'public' folder which holds my index.html file which I'm trying to access when I run localhost:4000.

Instead I get an error on the page saying "Cannot GET ". The console gives me a 404 error as well.

Comment: try this `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` assuming your `public folder` is in root with your `index.js` and then add the route like in [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63166169/1283672)

Answer (score 0):

To access your index.html file, you need to set up a GET route:

```
var express = require('express');

//App setup
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
   res.render('index.html')
})

var server = app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('listening to requests on port 4000');
});
```